# Android application just for tablets?

Tags: android

Is it posible to make my app to install only on tablets ??

1. I tried with minsdk version, but it doesn't work, because there is tablets with froyo, and now ICS is out :(
2. I tried with support screen, with setting small , normal and large to false, but HTC flyer is large screen and it is not supported :(

So my question is is it posible to make app for just tablets, but to include tablets with 2.2

Comment: *Tablet sized* devices running Froyo are not and should not be classed as tablets. If you want to target tablets, don't target these devices. Don't encourage the poor poor poor user experience

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that there is not a clear distinction between tablets and other devices. Some devices are clearly phones while some others are clearly tablets. But, the Samsung Galaxy Note is a phone or a tablet? Same for Dell steak 5, and many others.

Currently, last generation phones have screens of 1280x720, having more pixels than some low end 8" tablets.

You can not distinguish either based on the default orientation (landscape / portrait) since you can find both default orientations in both kind of devices.

Comment: It raises the question - *should* it be done? If your app requires a certain resolution, or a certain default orientation, then check for that...